# Why flicker when showing transparent window on Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi

I set `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`or`WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` in `CreateWindowEx()`, it is not transparent for a moment when the program is opened, and the transparent window is displayed after about 0.5 second.

I set `WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE` in `CreateWindowEx()`, and a transparent window appears immediately after opening the program

Why does it flicker and how to avoid this phenomenon by using `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`?

Sorry, I don't found answer in Google and English is not my native language.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, NULL, 100, LWA_ALPHA);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, BOOL)
{
    WNDCLASS wc = {0};
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("wndclass");
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 99, 71));
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, TEXT("Window"), WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 300, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    if (hWnd == NULL)
        return 1;
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    MSG msg = {0};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A window flicker when a program is opened.
[image]

The same when I click the caption buttons to maximize and minimize window.
[image]

I want to use the `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` property to make the main window immediately transparent, is there any way?

Comment: Your `WinProc` should probably handle `WM_CREATE` and call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` from there. This message is sent before the window is displayed.

Comment: @IInspectable This dose't answer the question.

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer. They are suggesting you try it. Lots of messages are delivered to your new window before `CreateWindowEx` returns a valid window handle. It might be relevant. You might be calling this function too late.

Comment: hmm, calling `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` after `ShowWindow` seem to solve the issue with initial transparency. However unlike `ShowWindow`, which does not actually display window until message loop is executed, `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` immediately displays window but with default background color and then when message loop is executed color changes to correct one. So `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` should probably be called even later, probably after some initial messages are pumped through message loop.

Comment: @paddy This doesn't seem to solve the problem. I set WM_CREATE and call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`, It still the case.

Comment: `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` doesn't have anything to do with making a window transparent.

Comment: @JonathanPotter What is the reason for that

Comment: `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` is a standard window style, that describes properties inherent to a window. *"overlapped"* here refers to what Windows 1 (and later) meant: A window that has a title bar and a border. `WS_EX_LAYERED`, on the other hand, is a flag that controls how the (external) desktop compositor treats the window. It's *also* a window style, but doesn't actually describe the behavior or presentation of a window. It's the thing that enables translucency, but that is established from the outside, not the window itself.

Comment: Fairly sure this behavior is baked into the OS. [Another complaint](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10069) about it. A basic workaround is BOOL arg = TRUE; DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED, &arg, sizeof(arg));

Comment: @IInspectable I just know what a overlapped window is . I can't understand that I use WS_SYSMENU style also causes window flicker, while using WS_ POPUP style creates transparent windows without window flicker. Is it because creating transparent windows using the WS_POPUP style can avoid drawing the window background？

Comment: @chacebai with newest Windows version 22H2 22621.1413, I cannot reproduce it, at least I cannot observe it but can reproduce it with Windows version 21H2 22000.1696.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmenableblurbehindwindow). The documentation has a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmenableblurbehindwindow#examples).

*Beginning with Windows 8, calling this function doesn't result in the blur effect, due to a style change in the way windows are rendered.*
So it takes on a transparent effect.

It also does not adjust the transparency and its transparency effect is not so good.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

It does not have window flicker with using negative margin values to create the "sheet of glass" .
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmextendframeintoclientarea
[image]

Then i used `SetWindowRgn` to redraw the window area Specified.

Adding the following code and **disabling layered window** can achieve the above effect.

```
   #include<dwmapi.h>
   #pragma comment(lib,"dwmapi.lib")
   ...
   ...
   static const MARGINS shadow_state{ -1 }; 
   DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &shadow_state);

   SetWindowRgn(hWnd, CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 800, 600), TRUE);// Specifies that the size of the redraw area matches CreateWindow.
```

However, you can't set transparency like `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`.

Comment: There are bugs when maximizing this.

Comment: @chacebai The SetWindowRgn function sets the window region of a window. The window region determines the area within the window where the system permits drawing. The system does not display any portion of a window that lies outside of the window region.

Comment: @chacebai Setting the window region of the CreateRectRgn to the maximum resolution(e.g：1920*1080) of the current screen maximizes normally.

Comment: Can't I use the Windows 10 style title bar?

Comment: @chacebai This method is not possible. It disables visual styles, so the window becomes classic. And using UpdateLayeredwindow requires bitmap.